# How to insert into table from csv/txt without using bulk insert?

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012

Is there any other way to insert into table from csv/text file except bulk insert?
By using query and not import by wizard.

Comment: Two other options using the LogParser command line tool and using PowerShell scripting are described at this link:  http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/11/28/four-easy-ways-to-import-csv-files-to-sql-server-with-powershell.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way you can do it which I have used when importing CSV data into a SQL database is via linked servers, if you install the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable onto your SQL server (make sure to use the correct x86/x64 version for your architecture):

[Microsoft Access 2010 Database Engine Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Then you can define a linked server like this:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'CSVLinkedServer', @srvproduct=N'OLEDB Provider for ACE', @provider=N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', @datasrc=N'S:\csv_location\', @provstr=N'Text', @catalog=N'*.csv'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'CSVLinkedServer',@useself=N'True',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL
```

Once you have that, any CSV file that you put into the folder S:\csv_location\ ends up as a table named filename#csv inside the default catalogue for your linked server.

I have a feeling that use of this particular provider isn't supported for this purpose by Microsoft, but we've found this to work brilliantly for data imports without having to resort to SSIS etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use BCP.EXE, which is a neat, although command line intensive way of importing data.

You can also use OPENQUERY to open the file from T-SQL and insert but this is can be unreliable.

Comment: Can you give me some examples?

Comment: There are many examples online. Here's a good one explainnig many options: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1207/different-options-for-importing-data-into-sql-server/. Why don't you try one and we can help you with any problems you have.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the SQL Server Import/Export Wizard[enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx)

Comment: No, I have to use query to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I had gone through many sites, of which i found the below code is the best and fast also easy compatible. Thanks to author.

```
BULK INSERT Table_1 FROM 'C:\Folder\file.csv'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a', FORMAT = 'CSV', FIRSTROW = 2)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).